# multiple form using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

First this is my first page which you will input how many forms you have to insert.

```
<table>
    <form method="post" action="additem.php">
        <tr>
            <td>How many records to insert? </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num" size="2" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Second will go to `additem.php` and will display form depending on the number you insert. For example you entered 2 , then it will display 2 forms. Display any numbers of forms are ok. the only problem is my jquery. The first form is only working but the 2nd , 3rd and so on are not.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showForm() {
    var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
    if (selopt == "branch") {
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (selopt == 0) {
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (selopt == "vicma") {
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $numbers=$_POST['num'];
        for($i=1;$i<=$numbers;$i++){
    ?>

    //This is my javascript which i have 2 
    values in first dropdown and will appear 
    another dropdown of the choosen value 
    on the first.Only first is working and others not.//    
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $numbers;?>" name="numbers" />
    <tr>
        <td><font color="black">*</font>Serial No: </td>
        <td><input type="text"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['serialnumber'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serialnumber']);?>" name="serialnumber[]"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Requested Dept:</td>
        <td>
            <select name ="type" id="opts" onchange="showForm()">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="vicma">Vicma</option>
                <option value="branch">Branch</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="f1" style="display:none">
                <select name="user1[]" id="opts"  onchange="showForm()">
                    <option value="ACCOUNTING" >ACCOUNTING</option>
                    <option value="CNC">CNC</option>
                    <option value="CONCESSION">CONCESSION</option>
                    <option value="HR">HR</option>
                    <option value="INVENTORY">INVENTORY</option>
                    <option value="SALES AND MARKETING">SALES AND MARKETING</option>
                    <option value="WAREHOUSE">WAREHOUSE</option>
                    <option value="MIS">MIS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="f2" style="display:none">
                <select name="user[]" id="opts"  onchange="showForm()" >
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM branch_tb";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $bid = $row['id'];
                    $name = $row['branchname'];
                ?>
                <option value ="<?=$bid?>"><?=$name?> </option><?}?> 
                </select>                  
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is not working in other `forms`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, my dropdown using jquery. only first is working, the second loop form and so on with dropdown is not working anymore. Doesnt display another dropdown anymore

Comment: Your `for` loop hasn't ended properly right? Also I don't see any other `forms` added here..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao , i already update it. my only problem is my jquery can't handle multiple form only the first one.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any `jquery` code in your given code..

Comment: When your for loop execute 2nd time your dropdown have the same id which was created by first so your function will not work because a single id is present so many time. So please update your select id on every  time of loop and you can also put you function and jquery,css  out side the for loop.

Comment: @Jeetendra , how am i supposed to do that?. since it depends on the number on the loop

Comment: Just put $i after each id and also passed it from your onchange function.

Comment: @Jeetendra , can you show me some example pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('.drop').change(function(){
         var id = $(this).data('id');
         var selopt = $(this).val();
         if (selopt == "branch") {
             $('#first'+id).hide();
             $('#second'+id).show();
          }
         if (selopt == 0) {
             $('#first'+id).hide();
             $('#second'+id).hide();
         }
         if (selopt == "vicma") {
             $('#first'+id).show();
             $('#second'+id).hide();
         }
    });
</script>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $numbers=$_POST['num'];
        for($i=1;$i<=$numbers;$i++){
    ?>

    //This is my javascript which i have 2 
    values in first dropdown and will appear 
    another dropdown of the choosen value 
    on the first.Only first is working and others not.//    
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $numbers;?>" name="numbers" />
    <tr>
        <td><font color="black">*</font>Serial No: </td>
        <td><input type="text"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['serialnumber'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['serialnumber']);?>" name="serialnumber[]"><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Requested Dept:</td>
        <td>
            <select name ="type"  data-id="<?=$i?>" class="drop">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="vicma">Vicma</option>
                <option value="branch">Branch</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="first<?=$i?>" style="display:none">
                <select name="user1[]" data-id="<?=$i?>" class="drop"  >
                    <option value="ACCOUNTING" >ACCOUNTING</option>
                    <option value="CNC">CNC</option>
                    <option value="CONCESSION">CONCESSION</option>
                    <option value="HR">HR</option>
                    <option value="INVENTORY">INVENTORY</option>
                    <option value="SALES AND MARKETING">SALES AND MARKETING</option>
                    <option value="WAREHOUSE">WAREHOUSE</option>
                    <option value="MIS">MIS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="second<?=$i?>" style="display:none">
                <select name="user[]" data-id="<?=$i?>" class="drop" >
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM branch_tb";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $bid = $row['id'];
                    $name = $row['branchname'];
                ?>
                <option value ="<?=$bid?>"><?=$name?> </option><?}?> 
                </select>                  
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: still the same @vinie , for the 2nd loop if you choose dropwdown. the result will display on the firts.

Comment: you are showing and hiding the form with dropdown change. So it is doing same

Comment: its working, its showing and hiding but the problem is with the second loop . the result will display on the first dropdown.

Comment: im sorry, i was just mentioning the 2nd loop. Because my loop is depends on the number of forms. so meaning not just 2 . but more than 2. sorry

Comment: Try updated answer it will work for any no of forms.

Comment: thumbs up. superb. i hope someday i'll be like you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set unique id for div. To achieve this, you can use $i value with "f" as below. Also pass $i in showForm().

```
<div id="f<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none">
                <select name="user1[]" id="opts" onchange="showForm(this,'<?php echo $i; ?>')">
                    <option value="ACCOUNTING">ACCOUNTING</option>
                    <option value="CNC">CNC</option>
                    <option value="CONCESSION">CONCESSION</option>
                    <option value="HR">HR</option>
                    <option value="INVENTORY">INVENTORY</option>
                    <option value="SALES AND MARKETING">SALES AND MARKETING</option>
                    <option value="WAREHOUSE">WAREHOUSE</option>
                    <option value="MIS">MIS</option>
                </select>
</div>
function showForm(val, num) {
                var selopt = val.value;
                if (selopt == "branch") {
                    document.getElementById("f"+num).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("f"+num).style.display = "none";
                }
                if (selopt == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("f"+num).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("f"+num).style.display = "none";
                }
                if (selopt == "vicma") {
                    document.getElementById("f"+num).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("f"+num).style.display = "none";
                }
            }
```